# First http request ending after second. How to fix it?

Tags: angular, http, asynchronous, web-applications

I have some life cycle of my app, that look like this:

1. Get request data.
2. Changing of data.
3. Put request data.
4. Get all data.
5. Show all data.
6. Go to point 1.

Problem is that the point 3 starting before ending of point 1 and point 4 starting before ending of point 4.
Code is located in different files.

**File 1. Service for http requests**

```
getObserver() {
        return this.http.get(this.urlAddress);
}

setTitleForId(
        this.http.put(this.urlAddress, obj).subscribe();
    }
```

**File 2. Component, that using File 1.**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpService.getObserver().subscribe((resp) => {
      this.obj = resp[this.id] as Obj;
    });
  }

 changeTitle(newTitle: string) {
    this.obj.title = newTitle;
    this.httpService.setTitleForId(this.obj);
  }
```

**File 3. This is the second Component**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.objs= [];
    this.httpService.getMemesObserver().subscribe((resp: Obj[]) => {
      this.objs= resp;
    });
  }
```

**Obj is:**

```
export class Obj{
    id: number;
    title?: string;
}
```

*It's my fifth day with angular.*
Maybe is exist something like semaphore?

Comment: Doesn't point 2 already need to know when point 1 is done?  Why can't point 3 wait to start until point 2 is done?

Comment: @ScottHunter, Yes, they should to know when the point above is done, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I suggest you read a little bit more about observables, this can be done using 1 long living observable

Comment: @Nickolaus, Do you mean about long living observable for get request, that will give new changes every time when they will be?

Comment: Think about just having an observalbe variable `request$` which chains all your operations... then you will be able to trigger the specific operation using `Subjects` I suggest reading some blogs to get a proper understanding of how observalbes work (my tip: https://blog.thoughtram.io)

Comment: ... you are using `observalbes` like `promises` but observables are much more powerful and are providing are wide range of functions and fields of usages